# Suitable Design pattern for building a 3D model

Tags: c#, design-patterns, 3d, modeling

I have implemented a 3D model application using DirectX api and C# .NET. Initially started with an intention to make the 3D model working and by now, all the code logic and UI stuff everything is in one *.cs file i.e., in main form.

Could you please anyone suggest me which design pattern is suitable for segregating my code in a proper way?

As MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) pattern is suitable for WPF application, Im under the impression that the same design pattern can be suitable for 3D rendering application.

Please suggest me if any other design pattern is well suitable for my 3D modeling application. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVVM design pattern is for frameworks with data binding, such as WPF and Silverlight, if you are using windows forms I'd suggest [Model View Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx) or [Model View Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx) patterns

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Yes, Im using windows form to display DirectX's device graphics object. As you said, I will not be using any data binding and I will only load an image file and will be changing the view and pixel data statically.